# How to dump the script from sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to dump a script for all the tables in the database. I guess it can be done through

```
database->right-click->tasks->export Data
```

But I don't know how exactly to do this. Please help. I am looking for a script with CREATE TABLE command.

Comment: are u looking for http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt ?  But this won't generate Create Table , this will create insert scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From SQL Server Management Studio, pick your database in Object Explorer and right-click, then `Tasks > Generate Scripts` and follow the wizard:

[image]